Do I need to create two separate projects on FedEx Developer Portal to use FedEx Ship and Track APIs?
I am integrating both the FedEx Ship and Track APIs into my MERN stack web app. I have successfully created a project on the FedEx Developer Portal, enabled both APIs, and added the necessary credentials to my environment. While the Ship API works correctly, I am encountering an error when attempting to call the Track API, and I'm unsure if both APIs can be used within the same project.
I created a shipment using the FedEx Ship API, and the request was successful, confirming that the API keys and credentials are correct.
Here’s shipment creation successful message:
Shipment created successfully: {
  transactionId: '034b54d7-e703-4e44-bcad-8f39d74dd16d',
  output: { transactionShipments: [ [Object] ] }
}
{ trackingId: '794798075411', shippingDate: 2024-09-06T00:00:00.000Z }

I then tried to call the Track API endpoint but received an error. I expected the Track API to work since both APIs are enabled in the same project. I was hoping to retrieve tracking information but instead encountered an error saying:
Error getting shipment status: {
  transactionId: '7e0f10bc-482f-46f7-91c2-b9a6b368b0ab',
  errors: [
    {
      code: 'FORBIDDEN.ERROR',
      message: 'We could not authorize your credentials. Please check your permissions and try again.'
    }
  ]
}

The error message makes me wonder whether I need to create a separate project specifically for the Track API, or if there’s something I’m missing in my current setup that would allow me to use both the Ship and Track APIs under the same project.
Could anyone clarify if it's possible to use both APIs within the same FedEx project, or do I need to configure them separately? Any guidance on resolving the tracking issue would be greatly appreciated!
